# Wrong behavior of RTL parameters hack with android 4.2.2

Tags: android, right-to-left

Since android 4.2, RTL languages are fully supported.
`Start` and `End` can replace `Left` and `Right` to define layout but android 4.1 and older don't support start and end. 
To use only one xml for both layout direction, we can use both `start` and `left` or `end` and `right` for retrocompatibility.
For exemple :

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />
```

[With android 4.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKiff.png), device use only `start` and `end` parameters and ignore `left` and `right` where both are defined. 
But [with android 4.2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjOHa.png) device use both parameters !
I have to use `layout-v17` folder to duplicate each layout with `start` and `end` parameters. 
**There is an other solution ?**

Comment: Are you sure it's not a problem of your custom view? I've got both parameters and I've never seen this behavior.

Comment: With the xml you posted, the behavior would be the same whether or not both pairs of parameters were being used. Can you post an example that shows a problem? What 4.2.2 device are you using?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution? I have the same problem! And it's a pain to maintain a bonus set of layout files :/

Answer (score 3):

Well i don't know if there is any official work around, so i have implemented a hack.

I added this to the end of my `gradle.build` file

```
String targetRTLDir = "res/layout-ldrtl"
task copyTask(type: Copy) {
    delete fileTree(dir: targetRTLDir)

    from 'res/layout'
    into targetRTLDir

    filter { String line -> line.replaceAll('Right', 'RTL_R') }
    filter { String line -> line.replaceAll('Left', 'Right') }
    filter { String line -> line.replaceAll('RTL_R', 'Left') }
    filter { String line -> line.replaceAll('android:layout_gravity="right"', 'android:layout_gravity="rtl_r"') }
    filter { String line -> line.replaceAll('android:layout_gravity="left"', 'android:layout_gravity="right"') }
    filter { String line -> line.replaceAll('android:layout_gravity="rtl_r"', 'android:layout_gravity="left"') }
    filter { String line -> line.replaceAll('android:gravity="right"', 'android:gravity="rtl_r"') }
    filter { String line -> line.replaceAll('android:gravity="left"', 'android:gravity="right"') }
    filter { String line -> line.replaceAll('android:gravity="rtl_r"', 'android:gravity="left"') }
    filter { String line -> line.replaceAll('android:gravity="start"', 'android:gravity="right"') }
    filter { String line -> line.replaceAll('android:gravity="end"', 'android:gravity="left"') }
}

preBuild.dependsOn('copyTask')
```

What it does is simply copy all your files from `layout` to `layout-ldrtl` and swap all `left` and `right`.

You can also replace all `left` and `right` to `start` and `end` and place it into the `layout-v17` folder if you want, but i've found that this works better since `android:gravity="start"` does not work!

I am fairly new to `Gradle`, so excuse me if this can be done with a much simpler script :)

Answer (score 1):

This post is old but still valid.

I have the same issue.
I found out that this issue only occurs when the view is wrapped inside a relativelayout. In that situation a alignparentright in combination with alignparentend results in a full width view, because it uses both the end and right parameter.
When you remove the relativelayout and replace it with a linearlayout only the alignparentend parameter cannot be used anymore, but you can use gravity. Android application itself makes sure that RTL ui gets mirrored